Jax dynamic slicing tracer array
To make this brief:
I wrote the following codes:
import jax
import jax.numpy as np

labels=np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2])
logits=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])

def body_func(carry,x):
    start_idx,arr=carry
    print(jax.lax.dynamic_slice(arr, [0], [jax.lax.tie_in(x, start_idx+1)]))
    carry=(start_idx,arr)
    return carry, carry

slices,=np.where(np.diff(labels)!=0)
print(jax.lax.scan(body_func,(0,logits),np.array(slices)))

but got
TypeError: Shapes must be 1D sequences of concrete values of integer type, got [Traced<ShapedArray(int32[], weak_type=True)>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>].
If using `jit`, try using `static_argnums` or applying `jit` to smaller subfunctions.
The error occurred while tracing the function body_func at /path/test.py:10 for scan. This concrete value was not available in Python because it depends on the value of the argument carry[0].

Here's the full situation:
I'm trying to develop a model to do phase recognition tasks, and I would like to normalize my logits phase by phase using jax.
For example, suppose I have the phase labels and logits:
labels=np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2])
logits=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])

I would like to normalize the first 4 elements in logits where in the phase labels they all belong to phase 0. Then the next 4 elements, because in the phase labels they all belong to phase 1. So the normalized logits should look like:
normalized_logits=[0,0.33,0.66,1.0,0,0.33,0.66,1.0,0,0.33,0.66,1.0]

Here's what tried:
import jax
import jax.numpy as np

labels=np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2])
logits=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])

def min_max_normalization(x):
    return (x - np.min(x)) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x))

def body_func(carry,x):
    jax.debug.print("carry is {}",carry)
    jax.debug.print("x is {}",x)
    start_idx,arr=carry
    print(jax.lax.dynamic_slice(arr, [0], [jax.lax.tie_in(x, start_idx+1)]))
    print(min_max_normalization(jax.lax.dynamic_slice(arr, [start_idx], [jax.lax.tie_in(x, x-start_idx+1)])))
    print(jax.lax.dynamic_slice(arr, [x+1], [jax.lax.tie_in(x, len(arr)-x-1)]))
    carry=(start_idx,arr)
    return carry, carry

slices,=np.where(np.diff(labels)!=0)
print(jax.lax.scan(body_func,(0,logits),np.array(slices)))

Basically, this is a debug version, the actual return value should concatenate three dynamically sliced array together. But I'm getting the error below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(jax.lax.scan(body_func,(0,b),np.array(c)))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/traceback_util.py", line 166, in reraise_with_filtered_traceback
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/lax/control_flow/loops.py", line 250, in scan
    init_flat, carry_avals, carry_avals_out, init_tree, *rest = _create_jaxpr(init)
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/lax/control_flow/loops.py", line 236, in _create_jaxpr
    jaxpr, consts, out_tree = _initial_style_jaxpr(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/lax/control_flow/common.py", line 64, in _initial_style_jaxpr
    jaxpr, consts, out_tree = _initial_style_open_jaxpr(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/lax/control_flow/common.py", line 58, in _initial_style_open_jaxpr
    jaxpr, _, consts = pe.trace_to_jaxpr_dynamic(wrapped_fun, in_avals, debug)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/profiler.py", line 314, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/partial_eval.py", line 2155, in trace_to_jaxpr_dynamic
    jaxpr, out_avals, consts = trace_to_subjaxpr_dynamic(
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/partial_eval.py", line 2177, in trace_to_subjaxpr_dynamic
    ans = fun.call_wrapped(*in_tracers_)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/linear_util.py", line 188, in call_wrapped
    ans = self.f(*args, **dict(self.params, **kwargs))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path/test.py", line 14, in body_func
    print(jax.lax.dynamic_slice(arr, [0], [jax.lax.tie_in(int(1), start_idx+1)]))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/lax/slicing.py", line 110, in dynamic_slice
    static_sizes = core.canonicalize_shape(slice_sizes)  # type: ignore
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 2086, in canonicalize_shape
    raise _invalid_shape_error(shape, context)
jax._src.traceback_util.UnfilteredStackTrace: TypeError: Shapes must be 1D sequences of concrete values of integer type, got [Traced<ShapedArray(int32[], weak_type=True)>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>].
If using `jit`, try using `static_argnums` or applying `jit` to smaller subfunctions.
The error occurred while tracing the function body_func at /Users/wuhaoyang/Documents/Research/Project_Surgical_Robot/Code/SSM_Med/test.py:10 for scan. This concrete value was not available in Python because it depends on the value of the argument carry[0].

The stack trace below excludes JAX-internal frames.
The preceding is the original exception that occurred, unmodified.

--------------------

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(jax.lax.scan(body_func,(0,b),np.array(c)))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path/test.py", line 14, in body_func
    print(jax.lax.dynamic_slice(arr, [0], [jax.lax.tie_in(int(1), start_idx+1)]))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Shapes must be 1D sequences of concrete values of integer type, got [Traced<ShapedArray(int32[], weak_type=True)>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>].
If using `jit`, try using `static_argnums` or applying `jit` to smaller subfunctions.
The error occurred while tracing the function body_func at /path/test.py:10 for scan. This concrete value was not available in Python because it depends on the value of the argument carry[0].

The reason why I'm not simply using a for loop is that I'm later going to wrap this function into another one that uses jit compile, so I want to do this with pure jax API. Any help is appreciated, please tell me if you need more information.

JAX arrays used in transformations like jit, vmap, and scan must always be statically-shaped (see Sharp bits: Dynamic Shapes for some discussion of this).
dynamic_slice allows you to slice a static length at a dynamic position, while you're trying to use it to slice a dynamic length at a static position, and thus you're seeing this concretization error.
To solve your problem, I would avoid scan and instead use JAX's segment_min and segment_max functions to compute the output in a vectorized rather than iterative manner:
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

labels = jnp.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2])
logits = jnp.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])

l_min = jax.ops.segment_min(logits, labels)[labels]
l_max = jax.ops.segment_max(logits, labels)[labels]

normalized_logits = (logits - l_min) / (l_max - l_min)
print(normalized_logits)
# [0.         0.33333334 0.6666667  1.         0.         0.33333334
#  0.6666667  1.         0.         0.33333334 0.6666667  1.        ]

If you want this to be compatible with jit and other transformations, you'll need to pass a static num_segments argument to your segment reductions to specify an upper-bound for the number of segments present:
l_min = jax.ops.segment_min(logits, labels, num_segments=3)[labels]
l_max = jax.ops.segment_max(logits, labels, num_segments=3)[labels]

